# Data Manipulation on dummy variables python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows(sample shown below)

```
Date       event  A B C D
2015-10-01  A     1 0 0 0
2015-10-02  A|B   1 1 0 0
2015-11-01  C     0 0 1 0 
2015-10-07  D     0 0 0 1
```

Here A indicates only event A occurred and A|B indicates both A and B occurred on a particular day. Now I have already formed dummy variables for the event as indicated above. Subsequently I want to club B,C and D into one event called 'minor'. So my output would look like:

```
Date       event  A  Minor
2015-10-01  A     1   0
2015-10-02  A|B   1   1
2015-11-01  C     0   1
2015-10-07  D     0   1
```

As you can see for second row,Minor is equal to 1 as B also occurs on that day. I am little confused how to approach this. In actual I have 20+ columns which need to be grouped into minor.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `df[['B', 'C', 'D']].sum(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `assign` + `drop`

```
cols = list('BCD')
df.assign(Minor=df[cols].sum(1)).drop(cols, 1)

        Date event  A  Minor
0 2015-10-01     A  1      0
1 2015-10-02   A|B  1      1
2 2015-11-01     C  0      1
3 2015-10-07     D  0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) if need only `0` and `1` output:

```
cols = ['B','C','D']

df['Minor'] = df[cols].max(axis=1)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
         Date event  A  Minor
0  2015-10-01     A  1      0
1  2015-10-02   A|B  1      1
2  2015-11-01     C  0      1
3  2015-10-07     D  0      1
```

Or if need sum values use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df['Minor'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
         Date event  A  Minor
0  2015-10-01     A  1      0
1  2015-10-02   A|B  1      1
2  2015-11-01     C  0      1
3  2015-10-07     D  0      1
```

Difference in changed `df`:

```
print (df)
         Date event  A  B  C  D
0  2015-10-01     A  1  0  0  0
1  2015-10-02   A|B  1  1  0  0
2  2015-11-01   C|D  0  0  1  1
3  2015-10-07     D  0  0  0  1

cols = ['B','C','D']

df['Minor'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
         Date event  A  Minor
0  2015-10-01     A  1      0
1  2015-10-02   A|B  1      1
2  2015-11-01   C|D  0      2
3  2015-10-07     D  0      1

df['Minor'] = df[cols].max(axis=1)
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
         Date event  A  Minor
0  2015-10-01     A  1      0
1  2015-10-02   A|B  1      1
2  2015-11-01   C|D  0      1
3  2015-10-07     D  0      1
```